# In VS Code, how can I break on exceptions when debugging ASP.NET applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, debugging, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I have an ASP.NET application built with .NET 5.0 (Core, not Framework), and I develop in Visual Studio Code. The application includes services running in the background, created in `Startup.cs`. For example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // -snip-
    services.AddTransient<MyServiceClass>();
    // -snip
}
```

When they throw exceptions, the console output shows (for example):

```
-snip-
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in MyApplication.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
-snip-
```

Why won't the debugger break on these exceptions? Is there some `launch.json` or `Properties/launchSettings.json` option I'm missing?

Comment: Will debugger skip exceptions? But I does not configure any parameters in  launch.json or launchSettings.json. The debugger could be break by exceptions.

Comment: @Karney. I'm not sure what you mean. The post says that the Microsoft debugger won't break on these exceptions.